# How to maintain User Session in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state, session-timeout

I am working on an application. When a user logged in, a new session is created and session destroy when he log out.

in web.config I am using `session mode = InProc` like,

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" mode="InProc" timeout="50"></sessionState>
```

As you can see that after `50 min` the session destroyed. All I want to know is how to maintain or regenerate user session if he/she not logout after 50 mins.
Thanks.

Comment: This 50 minute timeout is on that scenario when user is not active for 50 minutes, so it's sliding expiration rather then absolute expiration

Comment: you can persist the session in Sql server? Or if you are creating an ASP.NET MVC5, they have created a new Authentication middleware called "OWIN Forms authentication". Its a cookie based authentication and can persist for days.I suggest you consider that, its easy to implement.

Comment: What you can do to test out how this works is to temporarily reduce the timeout in you test environment to say 1 minute and then watch what happens if you refresh your page after 55 seconds and then again say 20 seconds later (to test the sliding expiry). To test the timeout refresh the page after 65 seconds.

Comment: Problem is that i am working on webform for a company and i am bound to use webform. And they restrict me not to use session state rather than inproc other modes are slightly slower the application.

Answer (score 0):

from the current config you provide asp.net will automatically make the session clear after 50mins. So in the application logic you have to implement the session validation to check if the session is empty and redirect the user back to login page.

Or instead you can implement manual page sign out logics, but creating a new page called 'logout.aspx' and in the page load event clear the session and redirect the user to login page. So whenever your user click on Singout link you can redirect the link to logout.aspx and it will clear the session and forward your user back to login page.

Comment: yeh the application redirects the user to login page if session is null